# put numbers from string into array

Tags: php

I have these multiple strings like the 3 below

```
 - Framing 50mm x 100mmx3.0m
 - Loglap 22x100x4.5
 - Decking 32 x 150 @3.0
```

What i want to do is extract the numbers into an array.

The numbers for each are either separated by `@` or `x`
So for `Framing` the first array value is `50`, second is `100`, third is `3.0`

I was thinking of using explode but the strings format aren't consistent.

How do i solve?

Comment: do the characters `x` or `@` denote anything specific, or is the only thing you're interested in the actual numbers themselves?

Comment: I'm only interested in the numbers, the `x` and `@` are just separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `preg_match_all` like as

```
$str = "Framing 50mm x 100mmx3.0m";

preg_match_all('/([\d.]+)/',$str,$m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 3.0
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/438260)

Comment: This is the one, the cleanest!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$string = "50mm x 100mmx3.0m";
$formated = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", ",", $string);
```

To replace all non-numeric values from a string and replace it with commas so it can be easier to convert to array, but the problem will be that the string that you want might be full of commas after commas.

The above code will result in: `50,,,,,100,,,3.0,`

So, the solution COULD be, replace double commas with an empty value.

$formated = str_replace(",,", "", $formated);

Now you have: `50,100,3.0,`

Exploding it will result in an array of numbers:

```
$array = explode(",", $formated);

Now you have ["50", "100", "3.0"]
```